# Jsonpickle in subclass changes data type

Tags: python, jsonpickle

In one of my projects I have a strange problem with `jsonpickle`, as long as I run it from the same file it works fine, but if it is run from a other class it changes the target object to dict. Below is simple problem reconstruction. My original classes are little complicated, but problem is the same.

P.S. Problem "disapears" when in `gui.py` I change `import data` to `from data import *` (with other code refactoring) but I'm not sure why...

Simple example:

1. data.py - alone works fine

```py
import jsonpickle
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Car:
    name: str
    model: str

class CarsList(List):
    # some other non important functions

    def length(self):
        return len(self)

class Company:

    def __init__(self):
        self.companyCars = CarsList()
        self.loadData()
        print(self.companyCars.length())

    def loadData(self):
        with open('cars.json', "r") as infile:
            json_str = infile.read()
        self.companyCars = jsonpickle.decode(json_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myCompany = Company()  # works fine
```

2. gui.py (not working)

```py
import data
class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myCompany = data.Company()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myGui = Gui()  # Not working !
```

Second file returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bart/costam/gui.py", line 15, in <module>
    myGui = Gui()  # Not working !
  File "/home/bart/costam/gui.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.myCompany = data.Company()
  File "/home/bart/costam/data.py", line 40, in __init__
    print(self.companyCars.length())
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'length'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is not available globally, so `jsonpickle` is not able to decode it.

In the [docs](http://jsonpickle.github.io/#module-jsonpickle):
`The object must be accessible globally via a module and must inherit from object (AKA new-style classes).`

This is also why the problem 'disappears' when you do `from data import *`.